# How to protect .bash_history file at Linux

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix, linux-kernel

For safety reasons, I want to protect my history file **(.bash_history)** at Linux. As you know, history file keeps last 500 command lines. **I want, nobody can change this file, except adding last line.** In other words, commands should be added **only and only the latest line**.

Comment: How do you maintain only the last 500 commands if you cannot delete older entries?

Comment: What are your concerns exactly? "for safety reasons" is vague, who's safety — yours, the file itself, or other peoples, and what's at risk? (hopefully kittens won't die!)

Comment: @l'L'l for the file itself and myself. If someone can change the lines which is in history file. My boss can accuse me like "you did this! its your history file!". do you understand? :) Actualy, its a homework from my boss :) he wants me to learn how to secure the history file :)

Comment: If you're wanting to use your history file for logging purposes there are better means of achieving that. If the main concern is to prevent the history from being reduced then the append only option (chattr +a) works.

Comment: @Colorist: If you have permissions to "secure" the file, you will always be able to manipulate it, too. For example you have to be root to use `chattr` which has been suggested here. But no one prevents you from temporarily undoing that change later, manipulating history, redoing `chattr` and killing your session so no obvious traces of the manipulation will be left.

Comment: @Colorist: Furthermore, only root can access your personal `.bash_history` by default. Now if someone else is root on that machine, even if you secure your `.bash_history`, they will always be able to work around your measures.

Comment: @MichaelJaros demius' answer is correct but "chattr" isn't available on mac osx terminal. i found that "chflags" works instead of "chattr". So, correct answer is **sudo chflags uappend /home/user/.bash_history**

Comment: @Colorist Thanks for the update and good to hear it worked out for you.

Comment: The exercise makes 0 sense. The goal reportedly revolves around "you did this! its your history file!", except bash does not have to log anything, not to mention ways to execute commands without direct bash involvement. You want to invest time into auditing instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your .bash_history file append only

`$ sudo chattr +a /home/user/.bash_history`

> a – append only: Writing to a file will only allow the file to be
>   opened in append mode for writing. That is you cannot redirect output
>   to overwrite the file, only append to it. Most normal file edit
>   operations, like opening the file with a text editor, will most likely
>   fail as the program will attempt to overwrite the file with the
>   changes and “permission denied” will be displayed. This attribute can
>   only be set by an account with superuser privileges.

The man page of chattr is [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr). Check for other attributes too, hope this helps somehow

Comment: Why do you answer a question *and* flag it as off-topic, preventing others from answering it?

Comment: Very simple, its offtopic question, but meanwhile I wanted to be helpful to the guy. And it's not me who decides when to prevent others from answering.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid `bash` from removing old history entries, you can set this in your `.bashrc` file:

```
HISTSIZE=-1
HISTFILESIZE=-1
```

`HISTSIZE` tells `bash` the maximum number of history entries to keep.

`HISTFILESIZE` tells `bash` the maximum number of entries the `HISTFILE` (usually `.bash_history`) should have.

Setting them to `-1` tells `bash` to use no limit.

Comment: What if someone comes around and changes the value to `0` or `1`?

Comment: I tried to provide an answer based on bash configuration (trusting the user), as deimus had already put one based on file enforcement. Anyway, if he cannot trust his own user, more harm can be done on `.bashrc` and other files. Also, `.bashrc` can be chowned to root, or set as immutable.